# Mikva Erev Shabbat (for men) - looking for a detailed work on this practice

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, mikvah-ritual-bath, soul

I would like to learn everything there is to learn about the practice of men going to *mikva* (immersing one's body in a ritual pool) on *erev shabbat* (Friday afternoon).

I am not looking for a *sif katan* in e.g. Mishna Berura than briefly outlines the basic, well known facts of this practice and Ezra's *takana*, but ideally a work dedicated to it. A *kuntress* or more. E.g. I would like to know:

1. Detailed information about the spiritual side of this practice. How it affects the soul; the Kabbalistic side of things; where this practice fits in the grand scheme of things etc.
2. Any *halachos* or "guidelines" (given that not all of this is *halacha* per se). E.g. what's the difference between a mikva kosher for women vs a mikva kosher for men vs pouring 9 kabin of water over one's head; should one refrain from cohabiting with one's wife after mikva until Shabbat or is that irrelevant; how many times should one dip and how?
3. *Segulot* (spiritual remedies) and other benefits of the practice.
4. Detailed history and anecdotes.
   etc.

Does such a work exist?

Comment: Very condensed version by Rabbi Mansour: https://itorah.com/daily-halacha/search-result/18,7,26,13,22,19,28,0,21,6,27,5,4,3,16,2,9,8,15,14,25,11,12,23,24,20/Mikvah-erev-Shabbat-/1/18526

Comment: The Arizal discusses this in several places (Shar haKavannot, Shar HaMitzvot) but I don't have the time to parse through right now. There totally should be a standalone sefer of everybody's shita on this

Comment: Another kitzur tidbit (including kavanot and Saturday morning) from Rabbi Mansour: https://itorah.com/daily-halacha/search-result/18,7,26,13,22,19,28,0,21,6,27,5,4,3,16,2,9,8,15,14,25,11,12,23,24,20/mikvah-erev-shabbat-/1/19809

Comment: @יהושעק thanks for making having asked this question so valuable to me already

Comment: Here's a nice compilation of Chabad sources, though they're not specific to Friday: https://www.mikvah.info/media/Vetaval_Bemayim_Hebrew.pdf